# How to read json file from my src folder in my react app using webpack-dev-server?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

machine.json:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Test",
        "imageUrl": "../images/panda.jpg"
    }
]
```

I have to read **imageUrl** from above json object and add it to `src` of `img` tag to see the image on UI.
React File:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import machineList from '../../resources/data/machine.json';

const Home = props => {
    return (
        <div className='home-component'>
            {machineList.map(machine => {
                return (<div className="card-wrapper" key={machine.id}>
                    <img src={machine.imageUrl} className="image" />
                    <div className="name">{machine.name}</div>
                </div>)
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

After rendering this component i am getting broken image.

Comment: Needs more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Missing an explanation in the question but in general:

You have to import your json file:

```
import images from './json-file-path'
```

and:

```
<img src={images[0].imageUrl}></img>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Esther-l Thanks for your response, I updated my question please check again and let me know if any thing else needed.

Comment: Are you sure about the relative routing of the `imageUrl`?